# Receive cross-client Google+ authorization code for offline access without library on iOS

Tags: ios, google-plus

It's funny but I can't find description of using HTTP requests to receive Google+ authentication code for offline access without iOS Google+ library.

Though example of it's integration is pretty straightforward, I don't want to add additional 20mb of weight to my iOS app.

I tried the approach described here
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline

but in case of server clientId I receive message abount incorrect redirect uri.

Could someone give me advice about it?

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches you could take that may/may not work for you.

- Installed app flow with internally stored client secret
- Web flow within a web view.

### Installed app flow

You will must likely need to use [the offline OAuth v2 / installed app flow](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp) which has redirect URI that has something like `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob` enabling you to redirect back to the browser, from there you can get a code to exchange for tokens.

In your case, I'm guessing you didn't create the right client type (installed application) which is preventing the `*:oob` redirect.

It's less secure to handle sign in in this way - if the user can extract the client secret from your app, they can do bad things like authorize a malicious 3P app with access to your application data.

### Web signin flow

An alternative would be to use the web signin flow from within a WebView, something that Apple may reject your app for and which is also insecure.

What you would do is host the sign-in solution on your web server, use the [JavaScript web signin flow](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/javascript-flow) to initiate sign in, request offline access, then exchange the resulting code for an access token and refresh token.

You would then store the refresh token / access token on the device and exchange it for an access token when you need access to the user data or exchange the refresh token server-side and pass the bearer token back to the iOS app when it needs access. This again is bad because it can expose other apps to user authorization credentials and could potentially allow a malicious 3P to access user data.

I can't recommend either approach. Is there a reason other than the app size impact that you can't use the library? I'll see if there is a good way to avoid the file size hit from the framework.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Though neither of both suggestions will work for me. I just can't understand why should I use a huge library with a lot of different APIs which I don't plan to call instead of simple HTTP request. I know that somehow my server clientId is matched with urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob redirect inside the library because I'm able to retrieve access token by using library auth code both on iOS and server. if library could do this then why my app can't?